# Extract £ or % value from Google Sheets with REGEXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets formula that extracts a £ currency value or a percentage discount from a block of text.

`=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"[\d,.£%]+")` - Extracts £ value or % discount (but other numbers too)

`=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"[\d,.]+")` - Extracts digits, commas, or periods

However, if the text contains any others numbers before the £ value or % discount they get extracted first.

How can I only extract the £ value or % discount from each cell in Google Sheets?

The maximum discount displayed is 2 decimal places maximum, which may help in building a formula to extract 4 digits left or right of the value.

EXAMPLE DATA

```
Amy Wills 44% Discount
1Direction Food 45.37% Discount
AllUnder20 £120 Commission
AATU 13.31% Discount
Tickets4You £70 Commission
AllAboutU £7 Commission
Andrea Cardini 4% Discount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=JOIN("", REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "£(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)|(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)%"))
```

*Details*:

- `£(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)` - matches a `£` and then matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits followed with one or zero occurrences of `.`/`,` and then one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)%` - matches and captures into Group 2 one or more digits followed with one or zero occurrences of `.`/`,` and then one or more digits, and then a `%` is matched.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

See the [RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EnI6uR/1).

Comment: This works great, however, I need the £ and % prepending or appending too, depending on whether it is a currency value or percentage.

Comment: @sigur7 So, use `£(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)%|%(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)£`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EnI6uR/2).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your samples, this should work.

=SUMPRODUCT(N(SPLIT(B2," ")))

You can see it at work [here in cell C2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IRwsy2AeXvfB6vq1qBWDz6KAPScEX-IF7AKZl0gHOrE/edit#gid=0).